# Frame[map] does not exist in Turtlebot 3?

Tags: python, navigation, ros, ros2

Going through the Turtlebot 3 tutorials, going step by step. While launching the first the script using python ( as in tutorials), I cannot see a fixed frame ( shows and error) while also the Navigation 2, does not let me activate the Startup as explained on the website. Could someone guide me where am I going wrong? Ref, this to start with https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#installation [Fixed Frame Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKXB.png)